# Selecting a rows in the standard .net 2.0 GridView Using VB.net & JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, .net-2.0, grid

Does anyone know how i can get the grid to select a row by clicking on any cell in the row?

The only way i can do this at the moment is by setting the AutoGenerateSelectButton property to True, but this adds a column to the grid with a crude "select" hyperlink and only selects the row if the word "Select" is cliked on.

Surely there has to be a better way!?!?

NOTE - I do not use C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some javascript to the row in `RowDataBound`

```
   e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = 
                    ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
                        (this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

There's a CodeProject article about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/JavaRowSelect.aspx), which goes into much more detail.

Comment: is there a VB.net example i could use as I dont use c# :(

Comment: My VB syntax is a bit rusty - but the basic idea is add the JS to the onclick attribute of the row - in the RowDataBound handler, something like

e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex));

Answer (score 2):

This is ancient, but here is the VB.NET equivalent:

```
Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
Dim postbacklink As String = cs.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(lbtnSelectRow, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

And if do not want to write any code check out the client-side selection of the [Telerik grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx). I am pretty content with it when using it during my web development.